# Unknown MySQL server host at godaddy

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, .htaccess

Hy there!
I am using linux based hosting from godaddy. My domain is registered at somewhere else. Now i need to change hosting of my website.

1) i changed the nameservers field at the domain registered site and added the godaddy nameservers.

2) I upload my website on godaddy in public_html folder.

3) I created a new username and database and uploaded my database there.

When i tried to check my domain it's giving strange error

```
"Unknown MySQL server host 'db2' (2)"
```

After a long time, i am posting my problem here. If anybody knows that what and where is something wrong then do share your ideas.

Also if anybosy knows that how to check the mysql server host information at linux based hosting of godadddy then also share it with me.
Advance thanks!

My initial lines of exported database files are

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.10.3
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: db2
-- Generation Time: Jul 01, 2016 at 11:22 AM
-- Server version: 5.1.73
-- PHP Version: 5.4.34

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `arikai2_2`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table ``
--
```

db.php

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "username","password") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("db_name");
```

Comment: If you're using `Linux` hosting, then your `database host` should be something like `mysql.secureserver.net`

Comment: Would you please set localhost as a host ?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy
you meant to say that in my db.php file i should change the hostname in first parameter of my query?

Comment: @MaulikKanani
I have alreday tried with the localhost but facing same error

Comment: @Ohgodwhy
mysql.secureserver.net didn't work

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure the values of Hostname is correct, check the database details you will see a field that says hostname and make sure you use it.
[image]

Comment: Where is this information ?
I am not finding it anywhere.
I am using cPanel for the very first time

Comment: Login to your account> Click  web hosting,You will see Manage Button and click it you will see your control panel

Comment: fine, now where is the settings in cPanel?

Comment: You have a search option Search for MySQL

Comment: i have 3 options. "Mysql databases", "Mysql Wizard","Remote mysql". In "Mysql Databses" i have no any option of action like you showed me !

Comment: Try to check which option will give you the database details, we are obviously using a different version of their cpanel

Comment: There is no any option providing any details about phpMyadmin. I have alreday checked all the folders and settings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116356/discussion-between-m453h-and-bc110402307-syed-zeeshan-haide).